# Is there a proper way to produce a OHLCV pandas dataframe using ib api?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, modularity

Here is the code that print out the data. However i don't see how to collect these data into a pandas dataframe. I used reqHistoricalData imported from ibapi (interactive broker) to request the data from TestApp class function which inherit EClient and EWrapper.

```
from ibapi.client import EClient
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.contract import Contract
from ibapi.order import Order
from ibapi.ticktype import TickTypeEnum
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os.path  # To manage paths
import sys  # To find out the script name (in argv[0])
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep, strftime, localtime 
from socket import error as SocketError
import errno

class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self,self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print ('Error: ', reqId, errorCode, ' ', errorString)

    def historicalData(self,reqId, bar):

         print (bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume)


def create_contract(symbol, sec_type, exch, prim_exch, curr):

    contract = Contract()
    contract.symbol = symbol
    contract.secType = sec_type
    contract.exchange = exch
    contract.currency = curr
    contract.primaryExchange = prim_exch

    return contract

def create_order(order_type, quantity, action):

    order = Order()
    order.orderType = order_type
    order.totalQuantity = quantity
    order.action = action

    return order

app = TestApp()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 0)

contract = create_contract('AAPL', 'STK', 'SMART', 'NASDAQ', 'USD')

app.reqHistoricalData(      reqId = 0, 
                            contract = contract, 
                            endDateTime = '', 
                            durationStr = '1 Y', 
                            barSizeSetting = '1 month', 
                            whatToShow = 'TRADES',
                            useRTH = 1, # =1 for RTH data
                            formatDate = 1,
                            keepUpToDate = False,
                            chartOptions = []
                         ) 

app.run()
```

and the output is:

```
20181031 222.52 224.23 206.09 218.86 1752000
20181130 219.07 222.36 170.26 178.58 7249186
20181231 184.39 184.94 146.6 157.74 6851826
20190131 154.89 169.0 142.0 166.44 6383564
20190228 166.93 175.87 165.93 173.15 3478346
20190329 174.28 197.69 169.5 189.95 4956586
20190430 191.64 208.48 188.38 200.67 3812115
20190531 209.88 215.31 174.99 175.07 5642571
20190628 175.58 201.57 170.27 197.92 3592406
20190731 203.28 221.37 198.41 213.04 3418242
20190830 213.82 218.03 192.58 208.74 5078104
20190930 206.42 226.42 204.22 223.97 3768842
20191023 225.13 243.18 215.13 242.51 3253952
```

What i am looking for:

```
           Open   High    Low  Close Volume
Date                                       
20181031 222.52 224.23 206.09 218.86 1752000
20181130 219.07 222.36 170.26 178.58 7249186
20181231 184.39 184.94 146.6 157.74 6851826
20190131 154.89 169.0 142.0 166.44 6383564
20190228 166.93 175.87 165.93 173.15 3478346
20190329 174.28 197.69 169.5 189.95 4956586
20190430 191.64 208.48 188.38 200.67 3812115
20190531 209.88 215.31 174.99 175.07 5642571
20190628 175.58 201.57 170.27 197.92 3592406
20190731 203.28 221.37 198.41 213.04 3418242
20190830 213.82 218.03 192.58 208.74 5078104
20190930 206.42 226.42 204.22 223.97 3768842
20191023 225.13 243.18 215.13 242.51 3253952
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do is create a queue from the module `queue`.

So that goes something like...

```
def create_queue(self):
    my_queue = queue.Queue()
    self.my_hist_queue = my_queue
    return my_queue
```

Then, when I define `historicalData` in the wrapper, I have it add it to the queue.  It goes like...

```
def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
    print("HistoricalData. ", reqId,
          "Date:", bar.date,
          "Open:", bar.open,
          "High:", bar.high,
          "Low:", bar.low,
          "Close:", bar.close,
          "Volume:", bar.volume,
          "Count:", bar.barCount,
          "WAP:", bar.average)
    self.my_hist_queue.put({'Request ID': reqId,
                            'Date': bar.date,
                            'Open': bar.open,
                            'High': bar.high,
                            'Low': bar.low,
                            'Close': bar.close,
                            'Volume': bar.volume,
                            'Count': bar.barCount,
                            'WAP': bar.average})
```

Then, it is relatively straight forward to iterate through the queue and put the historical data into a list of dictionaries.  This way, `pandas` can easily convert it into a data frame.  Here's how I do it...

```
def create_dataframe:
    ticker_list = []
    hist_storage = self.create_queue()
    num_of_days = 5 #put however many days you want
    data = self.reqHistoricalData(101, Contract, '', '{} D'.format(num_of_days), '1 day', "TRADES", 1, 1, False, [])
    for i in range(number_of_days):
        ticker_list.append(hist_storage.get())
    df = pd.DataFrame(ticker_list)
    print(df)
```

I hope this helps!  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

You could add a dataframe member to `TestApp`, and then add a row to it every time `historicalData()` is called:

```
...
self.cols = ['date', 'open', 'high', 'low', 'close', 'volume']
self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns=self.cols)

def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
    print (bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume)
    self.df.loc[len(self.df)] = [bar.date, bar.open, bar.high, bar.low, bar.close, bar.volume]
```

You would probably want to have a separate DataFrame for each `reqId`.

Answer (score 0):

For bigger data sets, use list of dicts. The bar object returning from the api can be translated into a dict, which can be appended to a list member of the api.

```
class IBApi(TestWrapper, TestClient):  # the actual API 'app' = API Object we interact with when sending/receiving
    def __init__(self):
        TestWrapper.__init__(self)  # requires the wrapper...
        TestClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)
        ###.....
        self.histbars=[]

def historicalData(self, reqId:int, bar: BarData):
   bardict={'reqid':reqId,'datetime':bar.date,'open':bar.open,'high':bar.high,'low':bar.low,'close':bar.close,'vol':bar.volume,'wap':bar.wap,'barcount':bar.barCount}
   self.histbars.append(bardict)
```

This resulting list of dicts easily converts into a dataframe:

```
df =DataFrame.from_records(apclient.histbars)

df
    reqid       datetime    open    high    low    close    vol     wap barCount
0   1   20220519 09:30:00   191.50  193.80  189.60  191.58  16178   191.778 7890
1   1   20220519 09:45:00   191.64  194.30  190.21  192.98  12876   192.433 6090
2   1   20220519 10:00:00   192.97  194.74  191.88  192.33  12974   193.27  7835
3   1   20220519 10:15:00   192.39  193.75  191.77  192.79  8370    192.906 4372
4   1   20220519 10:30:00   192.71  194.07  191.29  191.69  7269    192.425 3774
5   1   20220519 10:45:00   191.72  193.19  191.01  192.26  6565    192.093 3167
6   1   20220519 11:00:00   192.24  193.99  191.80  193.44  6664    192.998 3023
7   1   20220519 11:15:00   193.37  193.85  192.58  192.97  5105    193.132 2278
8   1   20220519 11:30:00   193.04  194.99  192.99  194.63  5787    194.196 2703
9   1   20220519 11:45:00   194.60  194.97  193.90  194.80  7207    194.467 2949
10  1   20220519 12:00:00   194.82  195.29  194.50  194.67  4862    194.839 2169
11  1   20220519 12:15:00   194.66  195.15  194.04  194.59  5753    194.605 2638
12  1   20220519 12:30:00   194.61  194.75  192.92  192.92  3618    193.83  1723
13  1   20220519 12:45:00   192.90  193.39  192.38  193.20  3921    192.911 1739
14  1   20220519 13:00:00   193.20  193.32  191.69  191.98  3309    192.602 1844
15  1   20220519 13:15:00   191.97  192.28  191.45  191.98  4601    191.883 2407
16  1   20220519 13:30:00   192.00  192.62  191.55  192.02  4240    192.034 2031
...
```

(excuse the manual format)
To do: simple lookup dict from request id to ticker, and format the datetime to pandas-readable datetime.